# Dynamic data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter and i am working on ecommerce template. By default whenever `index()` has been hit, it's showing all products in different sections (in html) and I want to make this dynamic so should I use queries in `index()` for get different type of records or there is any other way? This is my code:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        //echo "hello world";
        $this->load->view('index');
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First need to create database and table as per your requirement.
Then you can create model for reference check this link : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html

```
<?php 
class Blog_model extends CI_Model {

        public function get_data_first()
        {
                $query = $this->db->get('entries', 10);
                return $query->result();
        }

        public function get_data_second()
        {
               $query = $this->db->get('entries', 10);
                return $query->result();
        }
}
?>
```

After making model go to your controller and include it like:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('my_model');

        $data['first_list'] = $this->my_model->get_data_first();
        $data['second_list'] = $this->my_model->get_data_second();
        //echo "hello world";
        $this->load->view('index', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

Then use you param in index file like :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
if($first_list){
 foreach($first_list as $each){
    echo $each->my_param;
 }
}
?>
<?php
if($second_list){
 foreach($second_list as $each){
    echo $each->my_param2;
 }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

In Models folder write Home_model.php file for querying database.
Suppose you have a table called 'products'.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home_model extends CI_Model{
        public function __construct()
        {
               parent::__construct();
        }

        public function getProducts()
        {           
            $this->db->from('products');            
            $query=$this->db->get();    
            $out = $query->result_array();
            return $out;
        }

}
```

The function 'getProducts' will get you all the products from 'products' table.
Now in your controller load the 'database' library and the model.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {


     function __construct(){

         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model('home_model');
         $this->load->library('database');
     }
     public function index(){
         $products = array();
         $products = $this->home_model->getProducts();
         $this->load->view('index',$products);
     }

}
```

In index function function of controller you can call the 'getProduct' function of model.And can pass the data to view.

Documentation link for model.

[enter link description here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html)

I hope this helps.

Comment: @smriti baweja ....Can you please explain as I am not getting whats wrong with my answer.I would appreciate if you upvote it as i have posted the answer first.